# What is this "Show All Nodes" button in html source visible in dev tools?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, google-chrome-devtools, google-image-search

I have been inspecting [google images search](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=974&q=gunius&oq=gunius&gs_l=img.3...24587.26230.0.26591.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.0.0.2oxgiGulIi0) and found something that I have never seen. There is a button in the html source visible in the developer tools itself. As shown in the image below the button says `Show All Nodes (1296 More)`.

[image: Show all nodes]

Is this inbuilt in browser and appears when we have a huge amount of html nodes in the source or did google's javascript somehow changed the appearance of developer tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thats only an inbuilt dev tool button to allow you manage better big amount of tag elements, usually it displays when opening that tag can be really heavy.

Comment: Is it specific to only chrome? I couldn't find it in Firefox.

Comment: Yes, only chrome devtool @user31782